# How to design notification for group chat in sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, chat

I want to do this below to notify user but I am not sure about quality and slow query:

When someone insert new message to group chat SQL will `select all members of group` chat and then in the loop for each user it will `insert` `user_id group_id unseen_message_count`.Is that too heavy to do for each message in the chat because sometime people write really fast and doing this for each message?Have better option?

**Update version**

My sql is like below:

```
chat_seen table

user_id | group_id | unseen_count
```

when new chat `inserted` I will `update unseen_count for each user` then when they see `unseen_count`,I will `update unseen_count to 0`.I think it is heavy if I do this for each member of group,Is not it?

Comment: use a memory store for notifications, use a message queue for notifications, use sockets instead of polling for data (which then means you can just push updates), or some other solution that can run "async" (aside) the action(s) the user does

Comment: Message queues will be way, way better than a database for applications like this. SQL is really terrible at making pub/sub fan-out systems and FIFO queues.

Comment: @JimL I am confuse about what is the memory store for notifications?I heard that facebook use database for notification is not it?I asked because my chat system contain all feature the facebook chat notification

Comment: @tadman is not facebook use database SQL to create notification?

Comment: Facebook uses a whole bunch of databases internally, but it doesn't matter if they're SQL or not, you don't have direct access to them. **You must use their API** and MySQL is really terrible for accessing APIs.

Comment: @tadman but RabbitMQ  is slow and is not give guranteen to deliver message,when message recive to user it can be too late [article about it](http://objectzen.com/2016/10/14/not-use-rabbitmq-real-time-messaging/),have you other option?

Comment: A) Where does RabbitMQ factor in here? You've only asked about MySQL. B) RabbitMQ is not slow, and it can be configured to be durable, which is a form of guarantee, especially with acknowledgements turned on. C) If RabbitMQ doesn't cut it, use Redis, but that takes more work to get right. That article is a whole lot of hot air. For many applications RabbitMQ is fine. For **all of Facebook** it wouldn't work. Pick tools appropriate to the scale of your task.

Comment: You're spending more time here fretting and worrying than actually trying something. A simple Socket.io-based service with a RabbitMQ back-end will *easily* scale to tens of thousands of connected users. Beyond that you'll need to tune it better.

Comment: @tadman I have tried a lot but I learned that I am not able to use RabbitMQ because my website on shared host,are there another option?

Comment: Then try and find an already written chat application in PHP + MySQL and use that, or use it as an example for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @tadman I have wrote chat application and it works but problem is different, I am trying to achieve notification system which is like when someone write message to group then I want to send notification to all group members,and I am worry about my way because I should select all group members then with php foreach I should insert row for each of them,is it really terrible ?

Comment: That's why I'm saying look at existing implementations before re-inventing the wheel. You've got homework to do.

Comment: @tadman Ok I have searched again and I didnt found notificationsystem with messaging like facebook.I have trid a lot of ways,but all of them failed.Have you any experience about it?Should I update max 30 row for notification at chat  per each mesage

Comment: You're asking all the wrong questions here. There are chat plugins for all sorts of PHP frameworks. Start there.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, and it doesn't sound like a great solution, but not terrible either. The important thing to remember, is to ensure there are indexes on all the fields in your WHERE statements (e.g. group_id, user_id, etc).

You should also think about whether simply storing the id of the last message read for each user, might be enough to calculate that count without having to constantly update so many rows every time a message is posted.

Comment: But if I calculate for each user I will not able to count unseen ones,can do this:Please see updated question –

Comment: I have worked on your solution but I have seen that I should update last_message_id for each user when message is posted and if this user see this,are there another option